# Time independent Schrödinger equation values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I just read that the values as results to the time independent Schrödinger equation can be used for constructing a linear combination which will have  the result of the initial state of the particle's wave function. Is it right?

Comment: Please answer fast

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, from the time independent Schrodinger equation (TISE), the values (more accurately the energy eigenvalues), as well as the corresponding eigenfunctions, can be used to construct the wavefunction through some linear combination of these eigenfunctions.

However, what counts as 'initial' is not specified by the TISE at all, it is you that will have to decide exactly *when* the wavefunction starts to describe the particle with t=0, through the use of the time dependent schrodinger equation as well as the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks man , can you answer my other question too ? The link is here

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282127/how-do-you-solve-for-the-minimum-kinetic-energy-given-that-you-have-an-area-of-m